# scp -r ... but leave out (exclude) a specified subdirectory

Tags: scp

Here's the directory structure:

```
/a/
/a/b/
/a/c/
```

I want to copy everything, EXCEPT for the /a/c/ subdirectory.

```
scp -rp myserver:/a .      # this will copy everything
```

Q: How would I specify a directory to leave out in the scp command ?

Comment: The original motivation is that the subdirectory "/a/c/" is very large (gigabytes), so leaving it out will cut down the copy from minutes to seconds.

Answer (score 35):

I don't think you can, but you could use rsync? Something like this:

```
rsync -a --exclude=a/c myserver:/a .
```

Answer (score 6):

I think this might be the correct way of doing it so you are still using SSH, I haven't found a way to do it with scp - but using rsync over ssh might resolve it.

```
rsync -e 'ssh -ax' -av --exclude /a/c myserver:/a .
```

If you use the -n switch then it will create a dry run of the process:

```
 rsync -e 'ssh -ax' -av --exclude /a/c -n myserver:/a .
```

Comment: Also try `-rz` : `-e "ssh -i private.pem" -rz 'users@server:/full/path/'`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use extended globbing as in the example below:

```
#Enable extglob
shopt -s extglob

cp -rv !(./excludeme/*.jpg) /var/destination
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the perfect way to do it, but set the sub-directory you want to exclude as read-only. `chmod -R 444 /a/c` should do the trick. You'll get a "permission denied" error when it tries to write over that directory.